# Why is the current fragment null?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am creating a fragment in `OnCreate` method of main activity. Here is the code.

```
Object lockObject = new Object();
        synchronized (lockObject) {
            collectionPagerAdapter = new CollectionPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            collectionPagerAdapter.lstDepartmanlar = lstDepartmanlar;
            collectionPagerAdapter.lstMasaDizayn = lstMasaDizayn;
            collectionPagerAdapter.masaPlanIsmi = masaPlanIsmi;
            mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(collectionPagerAdapter);
            mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

                }
            });
            actionBar = getActionBar();
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
            for (Departman departman : lstDepartmanlar) {
                tab = actionBar.newTab().setText(departman.DepartmanAdi);
                tab.setTabListener(this);
                actionBar.addTab(tab);
            }
        }
        viewPagerCreated=true;
        fragment[0] = (FragmentMasaDesign) getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
```

After creating the `ViewPager` I want to get the current fragment but it throws me an error that says fragment is null. How can I know `ViewPager` completed and fragments were created? I have tried to use `synchronized (lockObject)` but it did not work.

Comment: where have you reached with this ? would appreciate if you reply :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:

```
fragment[0] = (FragmentMasaDesign) getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
```

from your `onCreate()` and instead add it in `onStart()`:

```
@Override
protected void onStart(){

    super.onStart();
    fragment[0] = (FragmentMasaDesign) getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(mViewPager.getCurrentItem());

}
```

In this scenario, I dont believe you need to use `synchronized`.

Comment: It still throws `NullPointerException  at com.res_otomasyon.resotomasyon.MainScreen.onStart(MainScreen.java:238)` this error :/

Comment: could you tell me what is at `MainScreen.java:238`

Comment: `fragment[0] = (FragmentMasaDesign) getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(mViewPager.getCurrentItem());` 
Line:238 is the code above that throws the error.